# Android, method to read and manipulate bytes?

Tags: java, android, file-io, assets

I am trying to read an XML file in bytes and decode it.

The problem I am having is joining the byte buffers into the String result.

if I do:

```
output += new String(buffer);
```

the text is corrupted at the point where they join. What kind of character do I need to insert to join them correctly?

Am I even doing this correctly?

I am using the following code to loop through the file and manipulate the buffer before storing it out:

```
 buffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
            is = getBaseContext().getAssets().open("xml/xml.xml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int r = 0;

        try {
            while(r != -1)
            {

                for(int i=0;i<buffer.length;i++)
                {
                    r = is.read(buffer);
                }

                deobfuscate(buffer);
                output += new String(buffer);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code,

```
buffer = new byte[1024];

try {
        is = getBaseContext().getAssets().open("xml/xml.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int count = 0, bytesRead = 0;;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024 * 2);
    try {
          bytesRead = is.read(buffer);

          while(bytesRead != -1)
          {
            deobfuscate(buffer);
            bytestream.write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
            count += bytesRead;
            bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
          }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String output = new String(bytestream.tobyteArray());
```

Comment: I got this to work, but I had to shift the "bytesRead = is.read(buffer);" to the bottom of the while and also perform it once just inside the try, the way you have written it, enters the while, reads bytes, finds there aren't any and kills itself.